# Cannot install FirebaseAuth using Carthage among with already installed firebase components

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, carthage

There are numbers of firebase components installed using **carthage** [(firebase/firebase-ios-sdk)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md) on our project which successfully works.

We tried to add **FirebaseAuth** in addition to already installed firebase components.

Carthage update command completes with no errors.  We did usual carthage library install steps. We added lines to Input Files and Output Files on Build Phase then add the FirebaseAuth.framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

When we tried to build the project, it **failed to build.**

#### We tried

- Clean build folder
- Delete derived data

And several other minor tries.

#### We've checked

Procedures by [(firebase/firebase-ios-sdk)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md)
- GoogleService-Info.plist added on the project target
- Added $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC flag to "Other Linker Flags" in "Build Settings".
- Delete Firebase.framework from the Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase.

#### Cartfile

Only firebase part, we have several other libraries installed.

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAnalyticsBinary.json" == 6.4.0
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseFirestoreBinary.json" == 6.4.0
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseMessagingBinary.json" == 6.4.0
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseAuthBinary.json" == 6.4.0
```

#### Error Log

```
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'Firebase'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthBackend.o)
  "_GTMFetcherStandardUserAgentString", referenced from:
      +[FIRAuthBackend authUserAgent] in FirebaseAuth(FIRAuthBackend.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Showing Recent Messages
:-1: Could not find auto-linked framework 'Firebase'

:-1: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcherService

:-1: Undefined symbol: _GTMFetcherStandardUserAgentString
```

We need to install FirebaseAuth.

I'm not even sure if it's a problem caused by trying to install FirebaseAuth using Carthage.  If it not possible we might to use Cocoapods but we prefer installing FirebaseAuth using Carthage.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was we did not add all the .framework files Carthage crated for FirebaseAuth to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Adding FirebaseAuth.framework was not enough but we needed to add quite numbers of other .framework files like ones starting with "Firebase...", "Google..." and "gPRC...".

Comment: I tried to approve my own answer but denied by stackoverflow system, it seems I need to wait two days to accept my answer...